# Make a Javascript/JQuery Slidedown menu start hidden instead of showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if you guys could help me with my Slidedown menu. It starts with the content showing and I want to make it start hidden so when you click the button it will show and it wont start showing the content.
Heres my code:

```js
var test = $('#test'),
    toggle = $('#toggle');


toggle.click(function() {
    test.slideToggle(1000, function() {
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>PASSWORD PROTECTION</title>
         <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='main.js'></script>
        <meta name="description" content="An interactive getting started guide for Brackets.">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<meta name="Keywords" content="">
<meta name="Description" content="">
<title>Down Menu Click</title>



</head>
<body></body>
    
<button id="toggle">Login</button></p>

<div id="test">
     <div class="slideTogglebox">
<h2>Login</h2>
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="password" id="values" />
<input type="submit" onclick="lg();" />
<input type="reset" onclick="location.reload();" />    
 </div>
<nil></nil>
</body>
</html>
        



</script>






  
    
    
    
    </body>
```

Comment: **css** `#test{display:none;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding 
    display:none; 
to #test in your style.css.

Alternatively, you could add it in the tag as well with:

```
<div id="test" style="display:none">
```

see below:

```js
var test = $('#test'),
    toggle = $('#toggle');


toggle.click(function() {
    test.slideToggle(1000, function() {
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>PASSWORD PROTECTION</title>
         <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='main.js'></script>
        <meta name="description" content="An interactive getting started guide for Brackets.">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<meta name="Keywords" content="">
<meta name="Description" content="">
<title>Down Menu Click</title>



</head>
<body></body>
    
<button id="toggle">Login</button></p>

<div id="test" style="display:none">
     <div class="slideTogglebox" >
<h2>Login</h2>
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="password" id="values" />
<input type="submit" onclick="lg();" />
<input type="reset" onclick="location.reload();" />    
 </div>
<nil></nil>
</body>
</html>
        



</script>






  
    
    
    
    </body>
```

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING!!! IT WORKED! I knew it would be something really simple, you are awesome ah now I should be able to get some sleep its like 10 to 1 am here in the uk